Как подключиться к phpmyadmin из kotlin приложения?
Пишу бота для Телеграм. у Заказчика есть БД и оно лежит на сервере webhost. Там расположен phpmyadmin и возник вопрос. как к нему подключиться? точнее, какую ссылку поставить в качестве подключения к БД (ссылка для подключения из веба выглядит примерно так https://cp2.webhost1.ru/user/phpmyadmin/). А может и не ссылка, честно говоря не знаю, потому и спрашиваю.
Подключиться пытаюсь таким образом:
val url = "jdbc:mysql://cp2.webhost1.ru/dataBase"
val username = "log"
val password = "pass"

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()
        DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password).use { conn ->
            println("Подключился!")
        }
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        println("Не подключился :( ")

        println(ex)
    }

пишет такую ошибку
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:53353', transport: 'socket'
Не подключился :( 
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:53353', transport: 'socket'


Всё оказалось проще, надо было указать нужный хост. Где его брать, я так и не понял, но покапавшись в других ботах нашёл нужный.
В  итоге вот так должен был выглядеть параметры подключения:
val url = "jdbc:mysql://s115.webhost1.ru:3306/DBname"
val username = "user"
val password = "pass"

